# Rails plugin to filter abuse words / expletives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, filter

I've been looking, but can't seem to find a RoR plugin/gem for filtering out abuse words / expletives from strings.

Do you know of a RoR plugin that does this?

*Ps. I do understand that there are many ways that such words can be displayed (like shit, shït, shıt, śhit, and śhiŧ). If a plugin can filter out such "words" as well, that's a bonus.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Fu-fu](http://github.com/adambair/fu-fu) can help you with this.